# Geometry nodes: is there a way to create a centerline of a closed curve/mesh?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, geometry

[image]

See above image for a reference. For this kind of closed curve I would like to create a centerline.
I have previously worked with an extension in Inkscape which creates a centerline but it is cutting the line at random locations.
I was hoping geomtery nodes could have a better result.

I have already tried around a bit but not very successful.

Basically the following:

- set position node with an offset based on the normal direction.
- merge by distance (merging only to vertices that are not directly connected to a vertex)

It kind of works for the general shape but the shorter 90° arms/angles just get deformed.